# UWP resources not found

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have an UWP application which is working fine on various machines but on one particular machine, it is crashing silently.

When I debugged the installed app through visual studio I figured out that it is not getting the resources on the XAML file e.g

```
{ThemeResource ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin}

{Binding TemplateSettings.DropDownContentMinWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}
```

The Output window is showing the following exception

> Exception thrown at 0x751641E8 (KernelBase.dll) in
>   myapplicationnamechanged
>   .exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error
>   (parameters: 0x80004005, 0x00000046, 0x05CDC7A8). Exception thrown at
>   0x751641E8 (KernelBase.dll) in Infonet.CStoreCommander.UI.exe:
>   0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x802B000A, 0x0000005C,
>   0x05CDC73C).
>   120|2018-11-28T14:45:50.1043744+00:00|INFO|2|App|.UnhandledExceptionHandler
>   line:59 Unhandled Exception -->
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with
>   this error code could not be found.
>
> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin
>   [Line: 0 Position: 0] Unhandled exception at 0x0F7F2DEB
>   (Windows.UI.Xaml.dll) in Infonet.CStoreCommander.UI.exe: 0xC000027B:
>   An application-internal exception has occurred (parameters:
>   0x116F1BA8, 0x00000004).

Comment: Please check that particular Windows build version is supported by your App. There might be the scenario in which few key/resources might have got changed with the newer build release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx) MSDN documentation `ComboBoxDropdownContentMargin` was made availalbe from Windows 10, Version 1511 (Windows SDK version 10.0.10586.0).

So if you are running your App which has Version lower than the supported version, in that case, it will throw an exception.